# Why Eclipse has two "Referenced Libraries" folders how "Referenced Libraries" folder is different from "Web App Libraries" folder?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ide

In Eclipse (latest Oxygen 3, JavaEE version) I have a "Dynamic Web Project" (chosen Project Facets are: Dynamic Web Module, Java, JavaScript + attached Runtimes: Tomcat 7.0).

Question 1): **In Project Explorer I see two folders: *"Java Resources/Libraries/Referenced Libraries"* and just *"Reference Libraries"* (at "Project root", outside of "Java Resources" folder hierarchy).**

[image]

**What is the principal difference between the two? Why do we have two same(?) folders?** In my case both folders somehow contain 100% same jar files, but what is the principal ideology of Eclipse IDE?

Question 2): **What is the difference between *"Java Resources/Libraries/Web App Libraries"* and  *"Java Resources/Libraries/Referenced Libraries"?*** Besides, how "Java Resources/Libraries/Web App Libraries" is different from just "Reference Libraries" (from Question 1)?

Question 3): **Which jars shall be put into *"Web Content/WEB-INF/lib"* and which jars into libs folder *outside* of "Web Content" folder?**   As I understand, all jars that are needed for classes to be deployed to a web server (Tomcat) shall be copied (not just linked) into "Web Content/WEB-INF/lib" folder and then they should be added to project build path from there ("Web Content/WEB-INF/lib" and not any other "Filesystem location"). But if so, *is it reasonable in any cases to have another "lib" folder which is different from "Web Content/WEB-INF/lib"? I think such a folder shall be present only in Java SE (non Dynamic-Web) projects* and therefore there is no reason for it in my project - is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 1):

Referenced libraries are for compile time resolution only, but webapp libraries are for runtime and compile time.

for example Tomcat libraries should appear in referenced libraries but is not present in webapp libraries.